# TYPO3 Fluidpages not loaded or no autoloader

Tags: typo3, flux

I got error in Fluidpages on frontend:
[image]

TYPO3 v6.2.11 
Flux v7.2.0 
Fluidpages v3.2.0 
vhs v2.3.1

As before I have setup many projects with Flux and Fluidpages but in latest version I am in stuck.

Comment: Do you use TYPO3 6.2.11 oder 6.1.11? The first one is supported by EXT:flux etc., the second one not.

Comment: @Jost, I have edited my question, It was mistake. Yeah, I am using latest version 6.2.11

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that you use old class names (the ones with underscores). `EXT:flux` removed support of old class names in version 7.2.0 (see [changelog](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/blob/7.2.0/CHANGELOG.md)), same for `EXT:fluidpages`.

To fix this, just replace your occurrence of `Tx_Fluidpages_Controller_PageController` with its new name: `\FluidTYPO3\Fluidpages\Controller\PageController`.

Of course you need to do the same thing for all classes in PHP as well as in all namespace declarations in your fluid templates.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Ghanshaym,

```
  5 >
    5 = USER
    5.userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    5.extensionName = Fluidpages
    5.vendorName = FluidTYPO3
    5.pluginName = Page
    10 >
```

May be helps

Comment: Hallo Ajay, thanks for you have tried to help me. That bug has been resolved in new version of Fluidpages 3.2.3